# Regex Pattern Match Digit preceding a alphabet only

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-group

I am trying to setup a regex but having an issue with the same.

The Text:

```
1)
1.2.3.4 - USER [01/Mar/2015:10:05:16 +0200] SSLv1.0 ABCDE-FGH-IJK128-LMN111 POST /abc/def/ghi/jklmn/opqrs/t1 HTTP/1.1 200 99 12345 http://somehost.somedomain.com:1234 balancer://abc_def_ghi_http_port_1234
2)
1.2.3.4 - USER [01/Mar/2015:10:05:16 +0200] SSLv1.0 ABCDE-FGH-IJK128-LMN111 POST /abc/def/ghi/jklmn/opqrs/12531631913/wqeqeqer HTTP/1.1 200 99 12345 http://somehost.somedomain.com:1234 balancer://abc_def_ghi_http_port_1234
```

The Regex:

```
(?:\/[^]\s\/(){},~:;=@#%&_\-]*)+
```

URL: https://regex101.com/r/qc9BOX/1/

Currently, the match for the above cases are:

```
1)
/Mar/2015
/abc/def/ghi/jklmn/opqrs/t1
/1.1
//somehost.somedomain.com
//abc

2)
/Mar/2015
/abc/def/ghi/jklmn/opqrs/12531631913/wqeqeqer
/1.1
//somehost.somedomain.com
//abc
```

The data is am getting is almost accurate, but in the 1st and 2nd matches of the regex i.e. `/Mar/2015` and `/abc/def/ghi/jklmn/opqrs/12531631913/wqeqeqer`
I dont not want the digits to be matched. 
Which means, my regex should find **/Mar/** only and not **2015**. It should match **/abc/def/ghi/jklmn/opqrs/wqeqeqer** but not **12531631913**.

Comment: Please tag your question with a language or a tool or a regex flavor specifically.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
(\/)([a-zA-Z\/]+)(\1)
```

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/qc9BOX/3/

Two issues with this:
1) I am missing /abc/def/ghi/jklmn/opqrs/t1
t1 because 1 is preceded by alphabet t, I should have it.

2) I am missing /abc/def/ghi/jklmn/opqrs/12531631913/wqeqeqer
Only the digits should be removed 'wqeqeqer' should be captured.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help. A proper explanation [would greatly improve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made